# JQuery two index check

Tags: jquery

I have two sets of two radio buttons. Each is called "index1" "row1" and are dynamically generated. I'm trying to build a JQuery call to check all indexi rows and if say index7 is no than row7 is no and disabled.

So far i have

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("name*='index'").change(function(){
         ----
    })
});
```

I'm not sure exactly what to place in the "name" name area for index cause i'm dynamically creating the table. with VB.net each with the name being "index1" like i said above. How would I map index and row together?

Comment: Could you recreate an example of a generated page then place in in jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Sure, https://jsfiddle.net/1sh4jzqq/

Comment: Trying to if first No is selected the second yes cant be selected